# SQL Statement to UPDATE and REPLACE values

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble writing a SQL Statement that would update and replace all the values in my Wordpress Database. I am a really just trying to replace all value of `wp_capabilities` with `wp_130638636_capabilities` in my `meta_key` column inside my `wp_130638636_usermeta` table.

See my screenshot below:

[image: phpmyadmin]
For example the line below will change one row:

UPDATE `wp_130638636_usermeta` SET `meta_key` = 'wp_130638636_capabilities' WHERE `wp_130638636_usermeta`.`umeta_id` = 6175;

But instead I only want to change the values of the `meta_key` that are `wp_capabilities` to `wp_130638636_capabilities`. If that value in `meta_key` doesn't have `wp_capabilities`, then the value shouldnt change.

Is this correct:

UPDATE `wp_130638636_usermeta` SET `meta_key` = 'wp_130638636_capabilities' WHERE `meta_key` = `wp_130638636`;

Comment: The screen shot doesn't show the entire SQL statement. Can you copy it in plain text?

Comment: added an edit above

Comment: "...meta_key doesn't have wp_capabilities..." -- do you mean the column `meta_key` is null, is an empty string, or does not include the exact text "wp_capabilities" (or maybe part of it)?

Comment: no I just want to replace the value in the `meta_key` IF it is `wp_capabilities` with `wp_130638636_capabilities`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is the correct statement. Update the column meta_key where meta_key is equal to 'wp_capabilities' to the new value 'wp_130638636_capabilities' This will not update any null values.

```
UPDATE
  meta_key
SET
  meta_key = 'wp_130638636_capabilities'
WHERE
  meta_key = 'wp_capabilities';
```

Comment: @a2b123 I would agree. Anyway, if this is a production database, make sure you make a backup before running this query. Better be safe than sorry. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update wp_130638636_usermeta Set meta_key =
    replace(meta_key, 'wp_capabilities', 'wp_130638636_capabilities')
```

Try this, I have just tried and it worked like a charm.